# Exporting from Blender to Three JS with materials intact on scene

Tags: three.js

I'm struggling to get an exported scene from blender into three.js and have been researching and experimenting for about two weeks now, however all information I can find on the subject seems to date back several years and is now too out of date to be of use.

I'm working with the following

- Blender: 2.7.7
- Blender Threejs export: 1.5.0
- Three.js: r76

I've tried a few hundred combinations of export settings and while I can always get the geomety exported correctly, the materials while referenced correctly as far as I can see in the JSON file do not seem to want to load in. This occurs with both embeded and referenced textures.

While I have plenty of code samples for loading in JSON with the ObjectLoader all the images, references I find are to much older versions of the exporter (which I have tried) and I've yet to find one thta contians materials, the closest I found was a blender export with colours.

If anyone has any resources for the exporter or the object Importer, or would be able to see any issues with the JON file t would be a great help. The documentation and resources I can find are rather thin on the ground for the newer versions of ThreeJS it seems.

**Here is a sample of the exported JSON** https://paste.ee/p/RH42a I encoded the textures on this one. For some reason it's also exporting upside down, but that can be easily fixed.

**Object loader**

```
var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
    loader.load('obj/test/blender/export/test.json', function(obj) {
    scene.add(obj);
});
```